# Redirecting to /onepage/success when gateway POST to /payment/response

Tags: payment-gateway

I'm owner of little e-shop. Platform - magento 1.9. 
For integration with my acquiring provider i copy-past another's code and modified for me. 
It's work, except this part:

```
public function responseAction() {
    if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

        $result = $_POST['RESULT'];

        if ( $result == "0") {

            $order = Mage::getModel( 'sales/order' );
            $order->loadByIncrementId( $order_id );
            $order->setState( Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true, 'Платеж ОДОБРЕН банком' );

        //  $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
        //  $order->setEmailSent( true );

            $order->save();

            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->unsQuoteId();

            Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect( 'checkout/onepage/success' );
        }
        else {
            $this->cancelAction();
            Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect( 'checkout/onepage/failure' );
        }
    }
    else
        Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect( 'vakavaka' );    
}
```

Gateway of my acquiring provider sending POST to /payment/response if payment verified and accept or declined: **result=0 for verified and accept, result=1(2 or 3) if declined or another reason**. With "result" param gateway send's many other's parameters.

**Work situation:**

When payment accepted by gateway and He's sent result=0 (via POST) to http://blahblah.blah/modulename/payment/response, then order is marked as PROCCESSING (with comment), magento sends email to shopper, but shopper redirects to http://blahblah.blah/**vakavaka**.

If gateway decline payment - order marked as canceled, and shopper redirecting to `checkout/onepage/failure` (code is work).

I specially mark bold "vakavaka" to attract attention. In my code no this `(Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect( '' );)`

What wrong in code?

Comment: WOW! Is my gateway sends data twice: fitrt, gateway redirect me out of his page to modulename/payment/response without POST, then next his sends POST to modulename/payment/response.

Answer (score 1):

It's weird how you're facing this problem. Your code looks fine. Try this though:

Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect( 'checkout/onepage/success' );
 return $this;

instead of

Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect( 'checkout/onepage/success' );

Comment: This solution is not work - redirecting to main page instead checkout/onepage/success

Comment: This is still relevant. Any ideas?

Comment: So after using the above code you are directing to main page and not vakavaka?

That is an improvement. Let me check

Comment: No idea, this code works just fine on my machine!

Answer (score 1):

is "***Require Customer To Be Logged In To Checkout***" in `System > configuration > checkout > Checkout` options set to `YES`?